# Android - Observation method did not work

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-livedata

The observer I created is not working. There are classes that I have run before, but the current one did not work. I could not understand where the problem was. The observation methods I created before are working.

**SingleLiveData.kt**

```kotlin
class SingleLiveData<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    private val pending = AtomicBoolean()

    @MainThread
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        if (hasActiveObservers()) {
            Timber.w("Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
        }
        super.observe(owner, Observer { t ->
            if (pending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observer.onChanged(t)
            }
        })
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun setValue(value: T?) {
        pending.set(true)
        super.setValue(value)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
class ExampleViewModel@Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {

    val event = SingleLiveData<ExampleViewEvent>()

    fun goToHome(userId: Long) {
        event.postValue(ExampleViewEvent.GoToHome(userId))
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    observe(viewModel.event, ::onViewEvent)
}

private fun onViewEvent(viewEvent: ExampleViewEvent) {
    when (viewEvent) {
        is ExampleViewEvent.GoToHome ->
            findNavController().navigate(
                ExampleFragmentDirections
                    .actionExampleFragmentToHomeFragment(viewEvent.id))
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

**observe() Method:**

```kotlin
fun <T> LifecycleOwner.observe(liveData: LiveData<T>, observer: (T) -> Unit) {
    liveData.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let { t -> observer(t) }
    })
}


fun <T> LifecycleOwner.observe(liveData: MutableLiveData<T>, observer: (T) -> Unit) {
    liveData.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let { t -> observer(t) }
    })
}
```

**NOTE: hasActiveObservers() return false.**

Comment: Can you post your `observe()` method which you're using in Fragment?

Comment: Can you check my edit?

Comment: Have you tried w/o ur observe method? Also, use viewLifecycleOwner in fragments.

Comment: Yes. I tried but not working...